# Восстановление удаленных файлов windows

Tags: windows, восстановление

Здравствуйте. Произошла катастрофа. Нужно было переустанавливать Windows, и прежде чем сделать это я залил архив размером 10гб на один из файлообменников сроком на 5 дней. К сожалению, сыграл тот самый случай: Я забл скачать этот архив. Соответственно, все данные с файлообменника были стерты. Если ли надежда восстановить файлы (я знаю название папок и пару имен фотографий) спустя 7 дней после переустановки Windows? Делал я полную переустановку, абсолютно все удалил. Я накачал кучу программ восстанавливающие удаленные файлы, но все тщетно. Какие варианты, кроме как "все пропало" вы можете еще предложить? В том архиве было все, абсолютно все.

Comment: http://1pchelp.ru/problemyi-pk/vosstanovlenie-dannyx-s-zhestkogo-diska-fleshki.html почитай на досугеможет чего длясебя почерпнешь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать различные программы для восстановления удалённых файлов.
Мне нравится [Recuva](http://filehippo.com/download_recuva/). Однако, времени прошло много, поэтому, скорее всего, большая часть данных уже перезаписана и восстановить удастся немногое.

Другой вариант - попытаться обратиться в поддержку файлообменника с предложением купить этот файл (ну какой-то их тариф, который позволяет хранить файлы, или ещё что-то - в общем, уже с ними разбираться). Фишка в том, что для подобных сайтов может быть важно отсутствие фрагментированности на дисках, что означает, что физическое удаление файлов происходит намного реже, чем их убирание из каталога. Потенциально у них есть неудалённый файл, но просто так они его точно не отдадут.

А вообще, при установке системы надо делить диск хотя бы на 2 раздела - один под систему, а второй - под данные. А ещё можно использовать кучу сервисов, в которых время хранения файлов не ограничено.

> filemail

Из любопытства пообщался с их поддержкой, а именно

> Njål
>   Active in the last 15m
>   CEO
>   12:00 am in Oslo, Norway
>   CEO and one of the founders of Filemail. Living in Oslo, Norway with my ripped wife and two awesome kids. Keepin it real by doing some support every day

закончили на этом:

> I can not go into technical details with you, sorry. If you want us to pursuit this any more - the starting price would be $5.000. We would have to make major traffic redirection and a considerable effort recovering these files. And we can not guarantee the result.

Хотя есть подозрение, что если бы я назвал ссылку, реакция могла бы быть другой. Мне кажется, что усилия по поиску несколько преувеличены, а вместе с ними и цена, так что можно попробовать поторговаться (но уже не мне, естественно).

Вот скриншоты всей переписки:

[image: Переписка]

Comment: Recuva не помогла. Я обращался в тех поддержку этого файлообменника в надежде как раз на то, что у них остались файлы. Но. к сожалению они сказали, что у меня бесплатный тариф и они не могут восстановить их т.к они безвозвратно удалены (если бы у меня был тариф про, они бы сохранились). Не могу ли я отнести жесткий диск в специализированный сервисный центр и помолиться о восстановлении?

Comment: @aloe, а ты предлагал им именно за деньги поискать файл? И желательно добраться до технических специалистов, а не до обычных консультантов. Про сервисный центр не в курсе, но полагаю, что они не смогут восстановить то, что было перезаписано. Возможно, какие-то куски найдут лучше, чем софт, хотя понятия не имею. Никогда с ними не взаимодействовал.

Comment: на сайте написано (filemail) что для бесплатных аккаунтов у них поддержка только до 7 дней. Я писал уже им, они ответили что никак не смогут восстановить мои файлы. Это просто катастрофа для меня, я без этих данных как без рук, ног, голоса и вообще мертвый..

Comment: @aloe, надо было не читать, а спрашивать. Попробовал у них узнать - без ссылки назвали $5000 за попытку что-то найти, со ссылкой могли бы и меньше назвать, думаю. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @aloe, попробуй найти кого-то, кто более-менее разбирается в подобных архитектурах - возможно это поможет как-то уменьшить цену.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Мне реально было интересно читать твой ответ. Я спрашивал у них так же, но немного по другому и цену они не называли. Даже если бы цена была бы не 5000$, то не думаю что ушла бы далеко от нее. Я не имею таких денег и поэтому, кажется, что я потерял все. Но все равно спасибо большое, что попытались помочь мне, даже выходя с ними на связь.
P.S Я тоже немного удивлен, что у них нет возможности сделать бекап или что-то типо того, как раз на случай, который случился со мной.

Comment: И да. Странно то, что 3 дня назад ссылка была недоступна, но спустя день они стала доступной, но загрузить с ней (по FTP, архивом или торрентом) Не предоставлялось возможным...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56437/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-aloe).

Comment: Спешу сообщить, что я восстановил абсолютно все файлы. Еще в прошлом году заливал их на google drive и забыл. Сегодня чисто случайно зашел туда и нашел этот архив. Вы даже не представляете какое счастье я испытал :)

Comment: @aloe, поздравляю!!! Хотя то, что за год не появилось ничего нового, - немного странновато :)

Comment: в прошлом году - это 26 декабря 16 года :) Спасибо, я ведь уже и не рассчитывал их достать, только залечивал рану, а оно вот как вышло. Буду теперь только такими сервисами и пользоваться!