# Что делать если удалил папку src с проектом?

Tags: java, android-studio

Я нечаянно удалил `src` папку в Android Studio. Не могу ее восстановить. В ней лежал весь проект. Что делать?

Answer (score 2):

Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши ваш проект в структуре проекта слева. Затем Local History -> Show History.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете восстановить проект до любой точки. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для более надежного хранения проектов следует использовать Git.

Comment: У меня максимум показывает 54 минуты назад. Что делать?

Comment: @StyopkinStepan Учиться пользоваться средствами для восстановления данных. Можно декомилировать jar, если есть, и оттуда вытащить код.

Comment: у меня остался apk-файл. Можно что-то с этим сделать?

Comment: @StyopkinStepan с помощью программ https://superuser.com/questions/181135/recover-data-from-full-format-on-ntfs-partition . AS удаляет просто с диска.

Comment: @StyopkinStepan можно [How to decompile an APK or DEX file on Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-an-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform)

Comment: @StyopkinStepan [Восстановление удаленных файлов windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647008/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-windows/647021#647021)

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Если указанный выше совет не помогает, то можно воспользоваться средствами восстановления данных. Например [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) Чем меньше аремени прошло с момента удаления, тем больше вероятность успеха, т.к. тем меньшая часть данных будет перезаписана.

Можете посмотреть ответы на вопрос [Восстановление удаленных файлов windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647008/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-windows/647021#647021).